# 'undergo' in passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

which sentence is correct?

> they **undergo** such instruction.
>
> they **are undergone** such instruction.

when do we use undergo in **passive form**?
I couldn't find any example for "undergo" in passive form but I read that it is transitive.

Comment: When do you use any passive form?

Comment: What do you mean? Have you ever read my question?

Comment: Well I'm indicating that the verb *undergo* gets passivized just like any other verb. Whether you should do it or not is contextual, and usually depends on the author. FWIW, your second sentence is weird enough that I dare say the first sentence is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that "undergo" has passive form as well??? give me an example.

Comment: http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/undergone

Comment: I didn't find any passive example there. Did you?? Do you know the difference between "passive" and "past participle"?

Comment: Yeah. My bad. But also, take a look at [here](http://translate.voov.me/InflectedForms/undergo). Rareness doesn't imply that it's wrong. The meaning of "undergo", as it goes along the lines of "experience", implies that its being used in a passive voice is rare.

Comment: I think it's not rare. it is NEVER used in passive form. **[transitive not in passive](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/undergo)**

Comment: @user115688: Don't take too much notice of that point. Grammatically there's nothing wrong with [examinations are undergone](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22examinations+are+undergone%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), whether followed by ***by** [whoever is undergoing the examinations]* or not. It's just not a particularly common form.

Comment: @user115688 despite my rashness in bringing up examples of a passive sentence with *undergone* :), also saying that it's simply *transitive not in passive* is rash. Don't get me wrong. I know what passive is! :) I was hastily trying to indicate what Stoney has said down there.

Comment: @MARamezani ok. the reference of "transitive not in passive" is [Longman English Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/undergo) not me. I know what Passive is too! If you want help anyone do not rush and do not underrate him/his. Comport the others like what Stoney B. did and get the perfect answer. thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passive *undergo* is pretty rare because the word itself expresses an essentially "passive-ish" meaning. The Direct Object of the verb is typically something which is done ***to*** you, not something which you do.

> Selected patients underwent an experimental operation to remove the tumor.
>   The people of Waziristan have undergone many invasions.
>   Candidates will undergo an examination to determine their fitness for the position.

Nonetheless, there are occasions when *undergo* is cast in the passive voice. This works exactly like any other passive: the Direct Object, the experience or treatment or whatever you *undergo*, is recast as the Subject of the sentence, and the verbform is transferred into the passive construction *BE + PastParticiple*:

> The operation **was undergone** by seven patients, and was successful in five cases.
>   Many invasions **have been undergone** by the people of Waziristan.
>   Examinations for the position **will be undergone** on April 30th.

This is a cumbersome use, and you will probably not find much occasion for it outside the classroom.

Note that your second example is ungrammatical, because instead of the Direct Object it uses the Subject of the active version as the Subject of the passive version:

> <sup>∗</sup> They are undergone such instruction.
>   <sup>OK</sup>Such instruction is undergone by them.

---

> <sup>∗</sup>  <sub>marks an utterance as ungrammatical</sub>